# License Cost Minimization Algorithm

Tags: algorithm, minimization

Suppose you own a company that must license software modules. You can only purchase one license per month. The costs of the software licenses are all different and are given by p1,,pn. The cost of all the licenses goes up by a factor of r (r is > 1) each month. Thus the price of
a license for the ith product is pi * r^m
 after m months. Design an n log n algorithm to find what order
to purchase the licenses to minimize the total cost to the company.

My first solution to this was to just order the most expensive licenses first, since they would be increasing in cost the fastest. However the answer feels too simple for me. Am I thinking about this wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Part of solving a problem like this is coming up with a proof that your proposed solution actually works. Based on what you say in the question, here is an attempt at this:

Suppose the best solution does not take the licenses in decreasing order of cost. Take two licenses Xi, Xj in the supposed solution with Xi < Xj and i < j. Now swap them. The costs of other licenses are unchanged. The cost from these two licenses changes from Xi * r^i + Xj * r^j to Xi * r^j + Xj * r^i, which is a decrease as long as r>1. So Any solution not in decreasing order of cost can be improved, and the best solution is indeed to order the licenses in decreasing order of cost.